# Reverse smallest currency unit

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

In order to use stripe with my Django application, I am using the following code snippet to transform e.g. 523.34 USD into 52334 CENTS. Currently, I have to handle a webhook sent from Stripe and therefore I have to reverse this. Meaning 52334 CENTS into 523.34 USD. I am a bit stuck with that and wonder if anyone could help me how I can reverse this calculation with my funciton:

```
def smallest_currency_unit(large_currency_amount, iso_code):
    iso_code = iso_code.upper()
    exponent = iso4217.Currency(iso_code).exponent
    if exponent == 0:  # 0 signals unused/nonexistent minor currency
        return int(large_currency_amount)
    return int(large_currency_amount * (10 ** exponent))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just worked out the solution. Had a small mistake before which is why it didn't work as expected.

```
return int(small_unit / (10 ** exponent))
```

Comment: In two days :) Currently it's not possible.